# What the data type does author mean in exercises for cpdt book?

Tags: coq

I'm reading [cpdt](http://adam.chlipala.net/cpdt/) book (great thanks to the author!). Author gives (unofficial) [exercises](http://adam.chlipala.net/cpdt/ex/). There is an exercise 6 below:

6. Using a reflexive inductive definition, define a type *nat_tree* of infinitary trees, with
   natural numbers at their leaves and a countable infinity of new trees branching out of
   each internal node. Define a function *increment* that increments the number in every
   leaf of a *nat_tree*. Define a function *leapfrog* over a natural *i* and a tree *nt*. *leapfrog*
   should recurse into the *i*'th child of *nt*, the *i*+1st child of that node, the *i*+2nd child
   of the next node, and so on, until reaching a leaf, in which case *leapfrog* should return
   the number at that leaf. Prove that the result of any call to leapfrog is incremented by
   one by calling increment on the tree.

The question is: what datatype does author mean?
What I was able to create is kind of

```
Inductive nat_tree : Set := 
| Leaf (n : nat) : nat_tree
| Node (nat -> nat_tree) : nat_tree.
```

Very the same definitions I was able to find in the internet. But this does not look to me like code above respects to author's requirement. Because author says `function increment that increments the number in every leaf of a nat_tree`. But with this definition there is only one leaf in any nat_tree. So, this is just a list, not a tree. One could add one more parameter in 'Node' constructor, like `Node (nat->nat_tree) (nat-> nat_tree) : nat_tree`, but this definition looks to me like it has exactly 2 children of each internal node, but author says about `infinity of new trees branching out of each internal node`.

So, I would like to ask for help with `nat_tree` definition. Or for a clarification why the definition above is good for the task. Or any else clarification which anybody is able to provide.

**Notice.** I think we do not break any honor code giving an answer. Author removed these exercises from the book and he says he does not support these exercises anymore. Author did not ask anywhere in book to hide sulutions (in opposite to, in example, Software Foundations book). More over, I was able to easily find several solutions to this task in the internet (but they all are like the given above). So, I think this question should be fully ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like the adequate data type according to the exercise description.
You can build trees with an arbitrary number of distinct leaves, e.g.
`Node (fun n => if n =? 0 then Leaf 3 else Leaf 5)`, `Node (fun n => Leaf n)`
or `Node (fun n => Node (fun m => Leaf (n + m))`.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I didnt think about it in this way.